# NullRefernceException when calling Setup

Tags: nunit, moq

I'm trying to do a simple `Setup` on mocked object, but I always get a `NullRefernceException` coming from the setup line:

[image]

What is the mistake that I am doing here?

Comment: In it's current form your question is very usefully because it is hard to search for. Please include your problem description as a written text and not just a screen-shot of the error, and also try to include the source code as text. I've tried to include this details in your question. Feel free to extend it or rollback if you don't like the way I've edited your quesiton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your setup is incorrect because you are confusing Moq with the `.ToString()` in the `It.IsAny<string>().ToString()`.

Because of this Moq cannot generate the correct matcher and throws an exception.

It is very easy to fix this, just remove the `.ToString()`:

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    mockDatabase = new Mock<IDatabase>();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    mockDatabase.Setup(m => m.DbQuery(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(ds);
    var sut = new BusinessClass(mockDatabase.Object);
    sut.SomeMethod();
}
```